# MySQL if available data goto page and show results if not available return check number

Tags: php, html, mysql, if-statement

I need a small logic which i can't able to get here

i need to get MySQL data from db and echo on .php file before that i need to check whether data is available or not if available goto one.php file to show results if data not available retunt back to previos page i used below code but no use please help

```
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect('localhost','asd_asd','13wda121asSS') or die ("Couldn't connect to server."); 
$db = mysql_select_db('asdasd_asds', $connection) or die ("Couldn't select database."); 

$warno=$_POST['search'];

$data = 'SELECT * FROM `cases` WHERE `warno` = "'.$warno.'"';

if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0) { header('Location: http://asdas.in/wcdsa.php')
} 
else
    {
    //We have no results and can't find the warranty, return a different page saying no warranty results exist
     header('Location: http://asdsd.in/wcasd.php'); //redirect
}

?>
```

here i need

```
$data = 'SELECT * FROM cases WHERE warno = "'.$warno.'"'; $result = mysql_query($data,$connection); //execute query
```

i need to execute query in other page like results.php where i will show the results

if data not exist in database show "NO DATA FOUND" in same page where query executed itself please help on this

Comment: Why not use mysqli or PDO?

Comment: no ineed mysql check database if data exists goto page1 else return to same page it's very simple but i am not getting logic here

Answer (score 0):

You did not execute your query. You need to execute query first. your `$result` is undefined.

**try this:**

```
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect('localhost','asd_asd','13wda121asSS') or die ("Couldn't connect to server."); 
mysql_select_db('asdasd_asds', $connection) or die ("Couldn't select database."); 

$warno=$_POST['search'];

$data = 'SELECT * FROM `cases` WHERE `warno` = "'.$warno.'"';
$result = mysql_query($data,$connection); //execute query
if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0) { header('Location: http://asdas.in/wcdsa.php')
} 
else
    {
    //We have no results and can't find the warranty, return a different page saying no warranty results exist
     header('Location: http://asdsd.in/wcasd.php'); //redirect
}

?>
```

Comment: @user2226832 : did you try this and did you understand your mistake ?

Comment: no ineed mysql check database if data exists goto page1 else return to same page it's very simple but i am not getting logic here

Comment: $data = 'SELECT * FROM `cases` WHERE `warno` = "'.$warno.'"';
$result = mysql_query($data,$connection); //execute query i need to ececute query in other page like results.php where i will show the results if data not exist show no data found here itself please help